How to verify maintained texts in Maintain Translations Tile App?
I'm trying to explore the Maintain Translations tile app. I have successfully translated labels of a custom CDS views. However, I am not sure on how to test it.
I have tried to login on a different language on SAP GUI and tried to view the CDS views but there was no difference.

on SAP GUI and tried to view the CDS views how did you view the CDS views in SAPGui?
